# DateField: selectedDate shows hours as 24:00:00

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

With a DateField component, the selectedDate.getHours returns as 24:00:00. I want it to return as 00:00:00.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

First, I set a variable in my Model that equals the selectedDate of a DateField component:

```
model.generalInfo.endDate = endDate_df.selectedDate;
```

Then I set another variable based on that value and I trace it out:

```
param.todate = df.format( model.generalInfo.endDate.toString() );
```

And this is where I see the time equal to 24:00:00

Comment: Not sure I follow your question. According to the docs, the [getHours()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getHours()) method of the Date class returns the hour, which will range from 0-23. It doesn't retrun "24:00:00". It shouldn't even return "24" because it ranges from 0-23. Please clarify.

Comment: It may be something you can change with localization; but I'm not sure.  Is there any country that has a time of, essentially, 0?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Sunil D - I updated my post to show how I am assigning and tracing the value. Maybe there is something wrong with what I'm doing there.

Comment: I've added an answer that should explain what was happening and how to fix it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the Flex [DateFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#format%28%29) to format the `Date` object. Have a look at the docs for this class, it has a [formatString](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#formatString) property that you can use to control how to output the date (or in this case the time).

If you give the `DateFormatter` a format string that contains "H" will output the hour in 24 hour format using the number range 1-24. If the format string contains "J" it will output the hour in 24 hour format using the range 0-23.

To get your desired output, use "JJ" in the format string, in addition to any other items. For example to output the hours, minutes, seconds:

```
var someDate:Date = new Date(2012, 11, 5);
var df:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
df.formatString = "JJ:NN:SS";
var formatted:String = df.format(someDate); // 00:00:00
```

Also, as @Flextras mentioned, there is Flash localization API you can use which has the added benefit of converting date/time strings to the values used by their locale. These are the `DateTimeFormatter` classes:

- [fl.globalization.DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html)
- [spark.formatters.DateTimeFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html) (Flex 4)

These classes format dates into the user's locale (or one that you specifcy), and format `Date` objects the same way the `DateFormatter` does.

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly the case! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like

```
  selectedDate.time = selectedDate.time - 24 * 60 * 60 * 60 * 1000
```

as a Date.time represents miliseconds since 1970 or whatever.. you substract 24 hours..

if it not works for you, you can create a new function or getter that converts it, or you can create a new mxml module, with DateField as superclass, and you can override the getHours method. tons of options to do this..

Comment: Definitely a very good idea. I've already created a function that rejiggers the Date object to output that. What I was really thinking was that I was missing something very simple and doing needless work.